# Uniform approach to access google drive, dropbox and box using android

Tags: android, dropbox, box

I need to develop a android application which can communicate with google drive, dropbox, box and other could services. is their any common method or android API that can be used to communicate with all?
tried Storage access framework but for that application need to be pre-installed in phone, which doesnt suit my requirements.